# How to get absolute position of point inside CALayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calayer, quartz-graphics

how can I obtain the absolute position of a CGPoint inside a CALayer. I need this for exact pixel drawing

Edit: Absolute to the screen

Comment: What du you mean by "absolute"?.. relative to topmost layer, pixel number in same layer, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit test the superlayers recursively, until you arrive at the root layer:

```
CGPoint originalPoint = // wherever from you obtain your original point
CALayer *layer = self;
CGPoint point = originalPoint;
while (layer.superlayer)
{
    point = [layer convertPoint:point toLayer:layer.superlayer];
    layer = layer.superlayer;
}

// here `point' will contain the exact position
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, I would assume the layer is attached to a view (otherwise you couldn't get absolute positioning)....so why not this instead of a loop: `[layer convertPoint:point toLayer:view.window.layer];'?

Comment: Equally good solutions. However, yes, it *assumes* a layer has an associated view.